# How to generate a RSA public key with base64 encoded String in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, rsa, public-key

web service return a `Key(String)`. then I `encode` it to `base64` `encoded` string. and then I want to create a `RSA` public key with this `base 64 encoded` string. how can I do it without any third party libraries.

this is how I convert the `server Response` to `base 64 encoded string`

```
let serverkeyData = serverPublicKey.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let base64encodedserverkeyString = serverkeyData?.base64EncodedString()
```

now I want to generate a `RSA` public key using this `base64` encoded string. according to this, using `base64encodedserverkeyString`. how can I do that.

> I don't want to use any third party

Comment: There is no in-built support for generating a `SecKey` from a base64 encoded String, so you are going to need some code. [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) can do it, so you could take the code from there if you don't want to use that framework

Comment: Since iOS 10 there is [`SecKeyCreateWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643701-seckeycreatewithdata) which can convert data in PKCS #1 format to `SecKey`. So if the string happens to be base64 encoded PKCS #1 data, you should be able to obtain a `SecKey` from it after decoding it from base64.